# SQL Counting Rows by Identifier Cust_ID: I need to count rows with 2 conditions. Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, counting

The Goal: To count number of customers who received Both Email 1 and Email 2.

The Data:

```
Cust Id  Email 
Tom      Email 1
Ben      Email 1
Tom      Email 2
Tom      Email 2
Jason    Email 3
Ben      Email 2
```

I tried:

```
Select count(cust_id)
from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
Where Email = 'Email 2' 
and Email = 'Email 3'

Select count(cust_id), touch
from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
having count(email)
group by 1
Where email = 'Email 1' 
and email = 'Email 2'

Select cust_id, count(email)
from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
Where email = 'Email 2' 
and email = 'Email 3'
group by 1
```

Expected Result: Should count Tom and Ben for a total of 5

```
count
  5
```

I know I'm missing something simple, help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please explain why the answer is 5.  The number of customers who received both emails is 2, not 5.  Your question also suggests that you want more than a single value as a result.

Comment: It is not a distinct count, Tom 3, Ben 2. I want a single count.

Comment: What if Tom got Email_3, too? How many times would you count him? Or If he got another Email_1?

Comment: @dnoeth it's not relevant. I only need to know if he got email 1 & 2 and the total count of occurrences.

Comment: Updated the goal to fix the confusion.

Comment: Well, the *count of customers* is 2, the number of emails send to those customers is 5 :-)

Comment: Yup, the row count would be 5, from my understanding that is how count works unless I specify distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing query doesn't work, because the value of email can't be both 'Email 1' and 'Email 2' within the same row. What you're looking for is called *Relational Division* and can be achieved using *conditional aggregation*. But based on GROUP BY this would result in 2 (customers received those email combinations). The same logic based on *windowed aggregates* returns the count of rows:

```
with cte as 
 ( select t.*
     -- flag rows matching a single mail
     ,max(case when email = 'Email 1' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cust_id) as flag_1
     ,max(case when email = 'Email 2' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cust_id) as flag_2
     ,max(case when email = 'Email 3' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cust_id) as flag_3
   from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current AS t
   -- filter emails to be matched
   where email in ('Email 1','Email 2','Email 3')
   -- filter for customers with combinations of emails
   qualify flag_1 + flag_2 = 2
        or flag_2 + flag_3 = 2
        or flag_1 + flag_3 = 2
 )
select count(*)
from cte
;
```

Edit, based on your comment *if I wanted a distinct count of customers would I :: select count(distinct cust_id)?*

Yes, this would work, but it's more overhead compared to traditional GROUP BY approach. Same logic, but returning one row per matching customer in the CTE:

```
with cte as 
 ( select cust_id
     ,max(case when email = 'Email 1' then 1 else 0 end) as flag_1
     ,max(case when email = 'Email 2' then 1 else 0 end) as flag_2
   from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current AS t
   where email in ('Email 1','Email 2')
   group by 1
   having flag_1 + flag_2 = 2
 )
select count(*)
from cte
;
```

Comment: I feel less dumb now, this is much more complex than I would have expected. I appreciate you taking the time. So If I only want to know who received email 1 and email 2:: Would I only keep the qualify flag_1 + flag_2? And if I wanted a distinct count of customers would I :: select  count(distinct cust_id)?

Comment: Why is the MAX necessary?

Comment: *If I only want to know who received email 1 and email 2:: Would I only keep the qualify flag_1 + flag_2?* Exactly. *Why is the MAX necessary?* The MAX is see if any row for this customer with that email exists.

Comment: What if OP has disjoint sets like `{E1, E2}` and `{E3, E4}`? When a customer matches on something like `{E1, E2, E4}` there's going to be some overcounting I think.

Comment: @shawnt00: There's no difference if sets overlap or not. Query #1 simply counts the number of rows and #2 the number of customers. Your UNION solution is somewhere inbetween when the same customers matches more than once.

Comment: Yes, you're right that mine could double-count. But I think that yours could still over-count say by including extra emails, say Email 4, via the `where` clause and still including it in the final result even though it didn't contribute to a matching set.

Comment: @shawnt00: Yep, correct, I didn't consider that. At least #2 and your query work the right way

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to count emails, not customers:

```
select count(*)
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.custid = t.custid and email = 'Email 1') and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.custid = t.custid and email = 'Email 2') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the general case. You can add to this very easily by appending more `union all` queries.

This does have the potential to double-count if your "matching sets" have any overlap. The idea is mostly a trivial way to combine the results of your individual queries with the assumption that the totals can simply be added together. It's hard to determine what your bigger-picture requirement is.

```
with data as (

    select count(*) as c
    from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
    where Email in ('Email 1' ,'Email 2')
    group by Cust_Id
    having count(distinct Email) = 2 -- because there are two emails in this match

    union all

    select count(*) as c
    from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
    where Email in ('Email 2' ,'Email 3')
    group by Cust_Id
    having count(distinct Email) = 2

)
select sum(c) from data
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to count *customers* but it seems you really want to count *rows* in some way. Maybe conditional aggregation is what you are looking for, after all. Something like

```
with cte as
-- conditional aggregation by Cust_ID 
 ( select Cust_ID,
     ,sum(case when email = 'Email 1' then 1 else 0 end) as email_1_count
     ,sum(case when email = 'Email 2' then 1 else 0 end) as email_2_count
     ,sum(case when email = 'Email 3' then 1 else 0 end) as email_3_count
   from WORK_TBLS_LOADS.aw_fpq_ajm_current
   group by Cust_ID
 )
-- summarize to just total counts
select count(*) as cust_count, sum(email_1_count+email_2_count) as row_count
from cte
where email_1_count > 0 and email_2_count > 0
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you both -- count of customers and count of emails. The way this works is-- we are keeping only those customers who share both of those email ids. Then we aggregate.

```
select count(distinct id) as num_customer, 
       count(*) as num_emails
from t a
where exists (select 1 from t b
              where b.id=a.id
              and email in ('Email 1', 'Email 2') 
              group by id
              having count(distinct email)=2);
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fesgxovtXcVvLDn3yskMbC/4)